# Silverlight and ComboBox: ItemsSource and SelectedIndex workaround

Tags: silverlight, combobox, itemssource, selectedindex

I have a SL ComboBox like the following:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

where UserLists is:

```
List<UserItem>
```

and each UserItem is:

```
public class UserItem
{
  public int Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Since ItemsSource Property is set by Binding, how is it possible to set SelectedIndex property to zero? When I try to set this property, I have an index out of range exception.

My goal is to set as selected the first item of UserList.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Make your `UserList` a dependency property and use the `PropertyChangedCallback` option in `DependencyProperty.Register()`.

```
public ObservableCollection<UserItem> UserList
{
   get { return (ObservableCollection<UserItem>)GetValue(UserListProperty); }
   set { SetValue(UserListProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty UserListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UserList", typeof(ObservableCollection<UserItem>), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata((s, e) =>
{      
   cmbUserList.SelectedIndex = 0;
}));
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide me the right steps to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting an index out of range because the data hasn't actually bound by the time you're specifying the index. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a data_loaded event or similar which would let you set the index when the data has been bound.

Could you use a data source that understands the concept of selected? Will ComboBox respect that attribute?

Comment: Thank you for your reply..What do you mean with data source? Could you provide me more information? Thanks again.

Comment: The object you're using for your data. In this case you're doing List<..> which is very generic. Can the ComboBox handle a different type analogous to the old ComboBoxItem? Alternatively if the ComboBox lets you bind to a property of the ItemsSource for the selected attribute, just add a selected property to your UserItem class.

Answer (score 1):

Use SelectedItem property of ComboBox for this goal.
Xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

View model:

```
public ObservableCollection<UserItem> UserList { get; set; }

private UserItem _selectedUser;
public UserItem SelectedUser
{
   get { return _selectedUser; }
   set { _selectedUser = value; }
}
```

For selecting first user in collection use command:

```
//NOTE: UserList must not be null here   
SelectedUser = UserList.FirstOrDefault();
```